# Delphi 11.3 Alexandria - SvCom services does not start on Win 64-bit platform

Tags: delphi, windows-services, delphi-11-alexandria

I am trying to convert a windows service based on SvCom from Delphi 10.4 to Delphi 11.3 with target platform "Windows 64-bit".

It seems that the service is unable to properly start.

When I try to run the service with DEBUG parameter to let it run in the SvCom window, as it tries to start two log are added to the window:

```
SetServiceStatus: hServiceStatus is invalid
SetServiceStatus: hServiceStatus is invalid
```

Then the service stops just as it does when running as registered service.

I tried also to create a virgin service that does almost nothing, and the behaviour is the same.

The code that should set service status is the following

```
const PSvSetServiceStatus: Pointer = nil;
function SvSetservicestatus;
asm
    call InitNTServiceDebug
{$IFDEF CPUX64}
    Mov rax, qword PTR [PSvSetServiceStatus]
    test rax,rax
    Jz SetServicestatus
    Jmp dword64 Ptr [PSvSetServiceStatus]
{$ELSE}
    Pop EBP
    Cmp DWORD Ptr [PSvSetServiceStatus],$00
    JZ SetserviceStatus
    jmp DWORD Ptr [PSvSetServiceStatus]
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

In Delphi 10.4 everything used to work properly, and also building the project with target platform "Windows 32-bit" it still works.

How could I fix this?

Comment: I haven't used SvCom in ages, is it even maintained anymore? Does it even support 64bit? The last version on its website is several years old. Have you tried reaching out to the author for help yet?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The latest version should support Delphi 11, but in the "What's new" section the last update is about delphi 10.3. I tried reaching out to the author but he did not replied yet. Do you suggest to migrate to something else, rather than using svCom?

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution!

The problem seems to be the "Address space layout randomization", a new feature introduced in Delphi 11.

You can find it on Project Options -> Building -> Delphi Compiler -> Linking: Here are two options:

- Support address space layout randomization (ASLR) Support
- high-entropy 64-bit address space layout randomization (ASLR)

These two options are set to TRUE by default on new projects.

SvCom uses assemblies, which is probably why it fails when ASLR is enabled.
By disabling even just one of these two options, everything goes back to working as it should.

Hope this can help other people who might have problems with SvCom or even just with assembly code on Delphi 11.